# jQuery : Re-index order after removing dynamically added items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating div blocks dynamically with item ids, label ids. While creating it is working as expected.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pr8167un/)**

**What I want is : after deleting *Row 2*, remaining items should be re-order as below :**

> - Row lable text should be read as **Row 1, Row 2, Row 3, Row 4** etc... instead of *Row 1, Row 3, Row 4*
> - Input values should read as **Input number 1, Input number 2, Input number 3, Input number 4** instead of *Input number 1, Input number 3, Input number 4* etc...
> - Remove anchor tag ids should read as **removeItem-1, removeItem-2, removeItem-3, removeItem-4** etc... instead of *removeItem-1, removeItem-3, removeItem-4*

**Where as, after deleting it is not working as expected.**

[image]

```js
var counter=1;
$("#addNewItem").click(function(){
  $('<div class="input-row"><span>Row '+counter+'</span> <input type="text" value="Input number '+counter+'"><a href="javascript:;" class="remove-row" id="removeItem-'+counter+'">Remove</a></div>').appendTo('#inputContainers');
  counter++;
});

jQuery(document).on('click', '.remove-row', function(){
  jQuery(this).closest('.input-row').remove();
})
```

```css
.rp-container{padding:10px 10px 0 10px;background:f3f3f3;width:500px;margin:20px auto;border:1px solid #cecece;}
.input-row{padding:5px;margin-bottom:10px;}
.input-row:nth-child(odd){background-color:#efefef;}
#inputContainers{margin-top:15px;}
#remove-row{margin-left:5px;}
input[type="text"]{margin:0 10px;}
#addNewItem{display:block;text-align:right;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rp-container">
  <a href="javascript:;" id="addNewItem">+ Add new</a>
  <div id="inputContainers"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any counter. Just rearrange the numbers dynamically, like this:

```js
$("#addNewItem").click(function(){
  $('<div class="input-row"><span>Row '+ ($('.input-row').length + 1) +'</span> <input type="text" value="Input number '+ ($('.input-row').length + 1) +'"><a href="javascript:;" class="remove-row" id="removeItem-' + ($('.input-row').length + 1) + '">Remove</a></div>').appendTo('#inputContainers');
});

jQuery(document).on('click', '.remove-row', function(){
  jQuery(this).closest('.input-row').remove();
  $('.input-row').each(function(i){
     $(this).find('span').html('Row ' + (i+1));
     $(this).find('input').val('Input number ' + (i+1));
     $(this).find('a').attr('id','removeItem-' + (i+1));
  });
})
```

```css
.rp-container{padding:10px 10px 0 10px;background:f3f3f3;width:500px;margin:20px auto;border:1px solid #cecece;}
.input-row{padding:5px;margin-bottom:10px;}
.input-row:nth-child(odd){background-color:#efefef;}
#inputContainers{margin-top:15px;}
#remove-row{margin-left:5px;}
input[type="text"]{margin:0 10px;}
#addNewItem{display:block;text-align:right;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rp-container">
  <a href="javascript:;" id="addNewItem">+ Add new</a>
  <div id="inputContainers"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create some function to reset values of your divs element. So, whenever `remove-row` is clicked first decrement the `counter` by `1` so that next time you click on add new it will start from correct value .Then , call your function to reset values.Inside this function you can loop through `input-row` using `each` loop then use `.find` method to get element which you need to change and add new value to your element using `.text()` and `.val()`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var counter = 1;
$("#addNewItem").click(function() {
  $('<div class="input-row">Row <span>' + counter + '</span> <input type="text" value="Input number ' + counter + '"><a href="javascript:;" class="remove-row" id="removeItem-' + counter + '">Remove</a></div>').appendTo('#inputContainers');
  counter++;
});

jQuery(document).on('click', '.remove-row', function() {
  jQuery(this).closest('.input-row').remove();
  counter--; //decremnt counter
  reset_values(); //call this rset values
})

function reset_values() {
  var count = 1;
  //loop through all divs
  $("#inputContainers > .input-row ").each(function() {
    $(this).find("span").text(count); //set new count to span
    $(this).find("input").val("Input number " + count); //set value
    $(this).find("a.remove-row").attr("id", "removeItem-" + count); //set id
    count++; //increment count
  })


}
```

```css
.rp-container {
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  background: f3f3f3;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
}

.input-row {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input-row:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

#inputContainers {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#remove-row {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

#addNewItem {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rp-container">
  <a href="javascript:;" id="addNewItem">+ Add new</a>
  <div id="inputContainers"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this question properly then You just need to call that method again where you are listing this rows.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.remove-row', function(){
  jQuery(this).closest('.input-row').remove();
  jQuery(this).closest().reload();
})
```

Comment: **@parmer harsh**, Thanks for the answer. But it is not working. getting error as **reload is not a function**

Comment: jQuery(this).reload();

Comment: or you can use this $('.your element name which you want to reload').your element name which you want to reload();

Comment: Actually, I want re-order all the elements lable like above mentioned in my question and reference image. PS: reload() function is not working

Comment: i am facing same issue as you.i am creating image block in the carousal after removing image block it will not refreshing.but below solution work for me you need to do some changes as your element name.try this in the funcation after removing the input row.

$('#carouselExampleIndicators').load(window.location.href + ' #carouselExampleIndicators', function () {
                            $('.carousel').carousel();
                        });

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use one renumbering function on both addition and removal of a row. This will keep everything numbered correctly from a central function, and you don't need to manually duplicate this job on creation of a new row, as you are now.

```
$("#addNewItem").click(function() {
    $('<div class="input-row"><span></span> <input type="text"><a href="javascript:;" class="remove-row">Remove</a></div>').appendTo('#inputContainers');
    renumberRows();
});

$('#inputContainers').on('click', '.remove-row', function() {
    $(this).closest('.input-row').remove();
    renumberRows();
})

function renumberRows() {
    let n;
    $('#inputContainers .input-row').each(function(i) {
        n = i + 1;
        $(this).find('span').text('Row ' + n);
        $(this).find('input').attr('placeholder', 'Input number ' + n);
        $(this).find('a').attr('id', 'remoteItem-' + n);
    })
}
```

I would also suggest you use the `placeholder` attribute on your inputs, because with all the solutions here your input values will otherwise get overwritten every time you change the rows. With placeholder you are providing the prompt for the user, but not messing with what they actually enter in the inputs fields.

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tvxuonLc/)